Change the system-wide dark theme programatically in Android 15 (Kotlin)?
This thread does not answer the question. See below.
I want to toggle the system-wide dark theme from my Jetpack Compose / Kotlin application. My app has the permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.
I know that it is possible to change the system-wide dark theme programatically in Android 15, because it works in the app Tasker (also with the permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS).
What does NOT work:

Previously, this could be done with UiModeManager.setNightMode(), but as of API 29, this method only affects car mode. I have tried it with UiModeManager as suggested in this thread, but nothing happens. I guess this is because UiModeManager.setNightMode() does only work in car or desk mode.

application.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
uiModeManager.nightMode = UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES


I have tried it with Settings.Secure:

Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, "ui_night_mode") // Value: 1
Settings.Secure.putInt(contentResolver, "ui_night_mode", 2)
Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, "ui_night_mode") // Value: 2

Changing the int value seems to work but still the UI does not change to dark mode. Maybe I have to trigger some kind of refresh? The system setting seems to be Settings.Secure.UI_NIGHT_MODE, but it’s undocumented, and changing it has no visible effect. While I can update the value via Settings.Secure.putInt(), the system theme itself remains unchanged and there is no error thrown.
It seems like adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 2 worked in previous Android versions to change the theme, but just like my programmatic variant, the theme remains unchanged.
What works in ADB is adb shell "cmd uimode night yes". It successfully switches the system to dark theme, but I have no idea if and how I could do this from my application.
What do I miss? Thanks for any help in advance.

That's what I did in my question. See bullet point 1. But I've also added it to the very top now.

Sorry, skipped over that when reading the question.
